# Does anybody know how to build qemu on raspian?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, raspberry-pi

I build qemu v4.1.0 branch on my intel x86 box, it builds fine.

If I build on a raspberry pi with raspian, I get this:

```
pi@pi205:~/git/qemu/qemu/build $ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/z/qemu/qemu/slirp'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/z/qemu/qemu/slirp'
  CC      migration/migration.o  
/home/pi/git/qemu/qemu/migration/migration.c:2008:24: error: implicit conversion from 'long long' to 'double' changes value from 9223372
036854775807 to 9223372036854775808 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int-float-conversion]
    value = MAX(0, MIN(INT64_MAX, value));
                   ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdint.h:124:22: note: expanded from macro 'INT64_MAX'
# define INT64_MAX              (__INT64_C(9223372036854775807))
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdint.h:109:24: note: expanded from macro '__INT64_C'
#  define __INT64_C(c)  c ## LL  
                        ^~~~~~~
<scratch space>:73:1: note: expanded from here
9223372036854775807LL
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:336:23: note: expanded from macro 'MIN'
#define MIN(a, b)  (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

I realize raspian is 32 bit, but 64 bit types are 64 bit types. I don't get why it works on x86 and not arm...

Same compiler, same everything.

Anybody ever tried this and get it to work?

Comment: qemu-system is available as an arm64 package https://packages.debian.org/buster/qemu-system .... Packages were built with http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu_4.1-1.debian.tar.xz → rules

Comment: yeah, but they don't work, if you read the mailing lists, they say those packages are horribly broken and don't work which is what I found by trying it. The remedy is to built it yourself which I am equally unable to do.

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/qemu-devel@nongnu.org/msg659961.html